# how to add multiple object values into single object based on some key in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a requirement where i have two arrays array1 contains some data like creation date and some Name properties and i have an second arrays with all the calender dates. So, i am comparing array1 with array2 when the creation date matches i would like to add data of first array data to second array object and also rename name property. Please find the below code example

```
var array1 = [{
Creation Date: 12/01/2022,
Name: "abc"
},
{
Creation Date: 12/01/2022
Name: "xyz"
}]

var array2= [{
Creation Date: 12/01/2022,
}]
```

I need below output

```
array2 = [{
  Creation Date: 12/01/2022,
  Name1: "abc",
  Name2: "xyz"
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.forEach()`, `.map()` and `.filter()` methods as follows:

```js
const array1 = [{'Creation Date': '12/01/2022',Name: "abc"},{'Creation Date': '12/01/2022', Name: "xyz"}];
const array2= [{'Creation Date': '12/01/2022'}];

array2.forEach(o2 => {
    const found = array1.filter(o => o['Creation Date'] === o2['Creation Date']);
    if( found.length ) {
        o2.Name = found.map(({Name}) => Name);
        //for Name1, Name2 properties, replace the above line with the three below
        /*const newData = Object.fromEntries(found.map((o,i) => [`Name${i+1}`, o.Name]));
        console.log( newData );
        Object.assign(o2,newData);*/
    }
});

console.log( array2 );
```

**NOTE**

You would benefit a great deal from using keys without spaces in them: see [JavaScript Guidelines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/MDN/Guidelines/Code_guidelines/JavaScript) ....

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Can i make them as below format 

`[
  {
    "Creation Date": "12/01/2022",
   Name1:  "abc",
  Name2: "xyz"
  }
]`

I need the above format as i need to bind it to UI

Comment: See comment under `o2.Name` line.